# How to extract and compare data from a given list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, python-datetime

CODE:

```
import datetime


data = [('09', '55', None, 'AC is on', None), ('10', '00',None, 'AC is on', None),('10', '13','fan is on', 'AC is on', 'light is on')]


def calc(data):

    print(data)               #prints the whole table
    while True:
        h=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H")              
        mi=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M")
        # z=[(i[2],i[3],i[4]) for i in data if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi]
        for i in data: 
            if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi:
                print (i[2],i[3],i[4])
                # sleep(60)
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc(data)
```

The first 2 elements inside 'data' are hour and minutes entered by user. The code should take user entered values , that is, data here. and should check with current time and should print i[2],i[3],i[4] as shown in code.

1)I just want the values to be printed once. But, it keeps on checking and prints value for 1 whole minute. The break statement isn't working.

2)Also, is it possible to somehow check and not to print the none?

Comment: if the current time is 10:30 AM and the user enters the time as - 
data = [('10','31','fan is on','AC is on',none)].
Then, we need to check till the user time == current time and print 'fan is on','AC is on',none.

Comment: worked great. thanks. By the way, can we not print the none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want your program to run until it finds a match between the current time, and the time specified in one of the tuples (`i`) in `data` : `(data[i][0], data[i][1])`, and then print the rest of the tuple : `i[2:5]`

1. The `break` is in the `for` loop scope, not your `while` loop. You exit the `for` loop, yes, not your infinite `while True` loop.
2. I would rather do `while match_not_found:`, then set `match_not_found = True`, and have a line `match_not_found = False` before your `break` statement.
3. You can use list slicing if you're going to use all remaining items of the tuple.
4. I added an extra `if` to exclude `None` of the printed items

Like that :

```
import datetime


data = [('09', '55', None, 'AC is on', None), ('10', '00',None, 'AC is on', None),('10', '13','fan is on', 'AC is on', 'light is on')]


def calc(data):

    print(data)               #prints the whole table
    match_not_found = True

    while match_not_found:
        h=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H")              
        mi=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M")
        # z=[(i[2],i[3],i[4]) for i in data if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi]
        for i in data: 
            if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi:
                print ([j for j in i[2:5] if j != None])
                match_not_found = False
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done few changes in code.

I dont know why you are using While= True . Because of which it is NOT coming out of loop . So i have removed it

Just added else statement to for check , you can remove it

```
import datetime


data = [('09', '55', None, 'AC is on', None), ('10', '00',None, 'AC is on', None),('10', '13','fan is on', 'AC is on', 'light is on')]


    def calc(data):

        print(data)               #prints the whole table
        # while True:
        h=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H")
        print(h)              
        mi=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M")
        print(mi)
        # z=[(i[2],i[3],i[4]) for i in data if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi]
        for i in data: 
            if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi:
                print (i[2],i[3],i[4])
            else:
                print ("It does NOT match")
                # sleep(60)
            break

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         calc(data)
```

EDITED (works now):

```
import datetime


data = [('09', '55', None, 'AC is on', None), ('10', '00',None, 'AC is on', None),('10', '52','fan is on', 'AC is on', None)]


def calc(data):

    print(data)               #prints the whole table
    while True:
        h=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H")              
        mi=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M")
        # z=[(i[2],i[3],i[4]) for i in data if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi]
        for i in data: 
            if i[0] == h and i[1]==mi:
                print (i[2],i[3],i[4])
                # sleep(60)
                exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc(data)
```

Comment: this is the reason, i've added while ---
if the current time is 10:30 AM and the user enters the time as - data = [('10','31','fan is on','AC is on',none)]. Then, we need to check till the user time == current time and print 'fan is on','AC is on',none.

Comment: @Captainaalooreportin'in so you mean , till if condition becomes true we need to check ? .If That is the case , Put the while loop back and in if loop add `exit()` after print statement

Comment: yup. worked! Thanks. Could you please tell me why isn't the break statement working? and why is it going in an infinite loop?

Comment: @Captainaalooreportin'in Break is just to come out of loop . Exit to come out of execution in simple words . Mark answer as correct